# How do I query all rows in an sqlite DB with same column value is present and which contains all values in a list?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| id   | email          | name |
| -----| -------------- |------|
| 1    | a@example.com  | joe  |
| 2    | b@example.com  | john |
| 3    | c@example.com  | joe  |
| 4    | d@example.com  | joe  |
| 5    | d@example.com  | dee  |
| 6    | d@example.com  | bri  |
```

I need to query the table for all rows where the same name has an email in the list "d@example.com", "a@example.com". This expected result would return rows 1 and 4.

Comment: What about #3? Define "the same name has an email in the list". Do you need all rows with name "joe"?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a subquery or CTE using INTERSECT to get the name, then join on name to return all columns.

```
with cte1 as (
   select name from my_data where email = 'a@example.com'
   intersect
   select name from my_data where email = 'd@example.com'
  )
select d.*
from my_data d
join cte1 c
  on d.name = c.name
where email in('a@example.com', 'd@example.com');
```

| id | email | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a@example.com | joe |
| 4 | d@example.com | joe |

Another query with same results:

```
with cte1 as (
   select name, count(*) as email_count
   from my_data
   where email in ('a@example.com', 'd@example.com')
   group by name
  )
select d.*
from my_data d
join cte1 c
  on d.name = c.name
where email in('a@example.com', 'd@example.com')
  and c.email_count > 1;
```

---

Answer (score 0):

```
select   id
        ,name
        ,email
from
(
select   *
        ,case when email = 'd@example.com' and count(case when email = 'a@example.com' then 1 end) over(partition by name) != 0 then 1 end as f
        ,case when email = 'a@example.com' and count(case when email = 'd@example.com' then 1 end) over(partition by name) != 0 then 1 end as f2
from     t
) t
where    f  > 0
   or    f2 > 0
```

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | joe | a@example.com |
| 4 | joe | d@example.com |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GbyYT3rr)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CTE` that returns the emails that you want and another one that uses aggregation and returns all the names with all the emails in the list.
Finally, filter the tables with the emails and names that are returned by the `CTE`s:

```
WITH 
  cte(email) AS (VALUES ('d@example.com'), ('a@example.com')),
  names AS (
    SELECT name 
    FROM tablename 
    WHERE email IN cte 
    GROUP BY name 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT email) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte)
  )
SELECT *
FROM tablename 
WHERE email IN cte AND name IN names;
```

Note that this query is scalable for as many emails that you want.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/z_WkeWLJ).